# How to specify an element's show and hide slide direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have:

```
<div class="splash-wrapper">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btnAccept" class="btn-input" value="ACCEPT" />

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.wrapper').hide();
     $('#btnAccept').click(function(e) {
          $(".splash-wrapper").hide("slide", { direction: "right"}, 200);
          $(".wrapper").show().show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
          $('#btnAccept').hide();
     });
 });
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1q09d72b/4/)

I'm having an issue adding sliding effect to the show method. I want the wrapper div to slide in right behind the splash-wrapper div, but right now the wrapper div slide in from the bottom.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1q09d72b/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `show` method on the wrapper twice, that's why there's no animation for it.

```
$(".wrapper").show().show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
             -------
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/1q09d72b/6/

---

And if you want them to be on the same row, there are many ways to do it, here's one using absolute positioning and hidden visibility instead of `display: none`: https://jsfiddle.net/1q09d72b/8/

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wrapper').css('visibility', 'hidden');
   $('#btnAccept').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".splash-wrapper").hide("slide", {
       direction: "right"
     }, 200);
     $(".wrapper").css('visibility', 'visible').show("slide", {
       direction: "right"
     }, 200);
     $('#btnAccept').hide();
   });
 });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

}

.splash-wrapper {
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="splash-wrapper">

</div>
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
<input type="button" runat="server" id="btnAccept" class="btn-input" value="ACCEPT" />
```